# SQL select statement inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I hava a table Person and a table Club.

I am using a sql statement to link Person to Club because there is a field PersonclubID that i want to link to the name of the club (ClubName). They are in relation with the ID as you can see in the sql statement.

Now it shows me all the persons who have a clubID but I also want those without one.

statement:

```
select * from Person AS p INNER JOIN club AS c ON p.club_id =c.id where isTrainer = false
```

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` in that case.  It will show you all `Person` rows and will have values for the `Club` rows that are matched. Rows that do not match will contain `NULL` values for `Club` values

NB: Experiment with the Joins a bit :)  Enjoy it

Comment: Clear, Simple and fast! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  If the answer is helpful, please 'accept' it :)  Welcome to Stackoverflow, have a nice day